# How to "Hijack" jQuery events and then trigger the default handler on some condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do something like Hijack the jQuery events of some elements, do a judgement, and then trigger the default handler if necessary.

Say I have a page with some inputs and buttons, and each of them are already bind with event handlers(click, focu key events, etc.) to do their jobs.

What I want to achieve is: whenever these elements' events are fired, I'd like to trigger my function first, this function will gather some data, and judge whether the execution should continue.

If no the corresponding handler should not be called like nothing happened.
If yes the original handler should be triggered with the original event data.

I don't want to change the default handlers to achieve this, so, is there a good way to do something like this?

Thanks

Comment: Tried `if` condition within handler ?

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: There is no foolproof way to do this especially if any event delegation is used , namespaced events exist, inline event handlers , event binding in ajax callabacks, other library event handling etc,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the **internal** method `_data()`

```js
/* add some event handlers */
$("button").on("click", function() {
    console.log("Button clicked");
});
$("button").on("click", function() {
    console.log("Button clicked 2");
});


/* hijack them */
var button = $("button"),
 boundEvents = $._data(button.get(0)).events;

$.each(boundEvents, function(key, eventHandlers) {
    // save the handlers from being "destroyed" by .off()
    eventHandlers = eventHandlers.map(function(eh) {
        return eh.handler;
    });
    
    // remove the event handlers
    button.off(key);
    
    // add the hijacked version
    $.each(eventHandlers, function(idx, handler) {
        button.on(key, function(e) {
            if ($("#cb").prop("checked")) {
                handler(e);
            } else {
                console.log("nothing to do...");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb" />
<br />
<button>Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining function at `.data()` of each that has events attached which is called at `if` condition within handler. If function returns `true` , do stuff , if function returns `false` do not do stuff

```js
$("div").on("click", function() {
  // if `check` returns `true`, do stuff
  if ($(this).data().check()) {
    console.log(this.tagName)
  }
});

$("input").on("focus", function() {
  // if `check` returns `true`, do stuff
  if ($(this).data().check()) {
    console.log(this.tagName)
  }
});

var elems = $("*").filter(function(i,el) {
  return $._data(el).events !== undefined
})

elems.each(function(i, el) {
    $(el).data().check = function() {
      // define condition here
      // if element has `css` `color` property set to `"blue"`
      // return `true`, else return `false`
      if ($(el).css("color") === "rgb(0, 0, 255)") return true
      else return false
    }
});
```

```css
div {
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div>click</div>
<input type="text" />
<span>text</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, like I mentioned, I want to do that without changing the handler code, the page is dynamically generated by server, and the elements are like general controls, so the handlers are not only for this situation, I'd like to have a solution that won't affect everything else.

Comment: @John.D _"so the handlers are not only for this situation"_ ? Is requirement to check a condition only at some events before running handler ? What is "this situation" ?

Comment: Only if I start a sub-process manually I need to hijack the events. the whole web page are using shared event binding code, if I change the handler code to do the check, that means for all pages all elements, the handler will do unnecessary check.

Comment: Tried @Andreas  solution ?